# i can't drop a rfa files after i canceled in Revit site component

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, autodesk, revit-api

I am creating a Revit plugin and I used WPF for dockable panels. On my local computer I have some plants (`*.rfa` files). In my project I am dragging and dropping the rfa file from WPF to Revit Site component.

First time it's working fine. But after I drag and dropped and canceled it, I tried again with the same file; I can drag it, but while dropping, it disappears. If I create a new project or open project, it's working normally. Problem is within the project.

Here is my drag method:

```
private void grdPlants_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         if (!AppData.IsLoggedIn)
         {
             AppData.HidePanelEvent.Raise();
             return;
         }

         draggedPlant = (PlantsWithTagName)grdPlants.SelectedItem;

         if (clickCount == 1 && draggedPlant != null)
         {
             string path = GetRFAFilePath(draggedPlant.id);
             AppData.SelectedPlantId = draggedPlant.id;

             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
             {
                 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

                 if (fileInfo.Exists)
                 {
                     DataObject myDataObject = new DataObject();
                     StringCollection coll = new StringCollection
                     {
                         fileInfo.FullName
                     };
                     myDataObject.SetFileDropList(coll);

                     if (doc != null)
                     {
                         DragDrop.DoDragDrop(grdPlants, myDataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                     }
                     ClearErrors();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     ShowError(PlanterPlugin.Properties.Resources.PLANT_NOT_LINKED, false, true);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 openWindows["plant_details"].Activate();
             }
             clickCount = 0;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Write(ex);
     }
}
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to provide more information to get help on this one. Are you seeing any errors in the debugger? Do you have all of your CLR exceptions turned on? Can you see anything in Visual Studio's output or maybe in the Binding Failures? If there are some other clues that you can help provide, someone might be able to offer some suggestions.